# Eliminar Linha com e-mail

Tags: php

Existe um formulário em PHP, que as empresas utilizam para postar as vagas.

As vezes elas colocam dentro do textarea algo como:

Enviar vaga para teste@algo.com

Eu gostaria de VIA PHP, eliminar todas as linhas (apenas a linha, por inteiro) que contive-se um e-mail. Segue o exemplo abaixo:

> Vaga para Pedreiro
>
> Salario: XXX
>
> Cidade: XXXX
>
> Enviar e-mail com curriculo para teste@teste.com.br
>
> Tarefa: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Deveria ficar:

> Vaga para Pedreiro
>
> Salario: XXX
>
> Cidade: XXXX
>
> Tarefa: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Lembrando que nem sempre vai ser Enviar curriculo para teste@teste.com.br. As vezes, eles escrevem diferente, como enviar dados para, envie um e-mail com se dados. Em fim.

Comment: Isso não é um placeholder ?

Comment: Eles quem? De onde é esse formulário? Se não é seu, por que vc acha que vai conseguir alterá-lo em PHP (uma vez que o formulário já vai estar no navegador após a consulta)? Vc sabe o nome do objeto com o textarea? Se sim, por que simplesmente não apaga totalmente seu conteúdo? Veja quantas dúvidas. Sinal de que a sua pergunta realmente não está clara. Por favor, edite-a para melhorar a explicação. :)

Answer (score 1):

Explode a text area em linhas diferentes.
Percorre o array resultante imprimindo apenas as linhas que não têm email

```
$linhas = explode("\n", $textarea);
foreach ($linhas as $linha) {
    // teste básico para presença de email
    if (!preg_match('/[a-z0-9]+@[-a-z0-0]+\.[a-z]+/', $linha)) {
        echo $linha;
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigada. Como seria a preg_match para http e telefone?

Comment: Para http: `preg_match('/https?:\/\//', $linha)`; para telefone (ou melhor, para 9 digitos seguidos): `preg_match('/[0-9]{9}/')`, se quiseres reconhecer números com espaços ou traços vai ser preciso complicar a *regular expression*.

Answer (score 1):

A pergunta está muito mal formulada, por isso você recebeu tantos negativos, espero que você edite ele para que as pessoas voltem a lhe positivar. Mas pelo que entendi, você quer filtrar o e-mail do campo textarea, para fazer isso, há duas maneiras, você pode bloquear a digitação de email usando javascript:

```
<script>
    function removerEmail(input)
    {
       input.value = input.value.replace(/(.*)[a-z0-9\.\_\-]+@[a-z0-9\.\_\-]+\.[a-z]+(.*)/gi,'');
    }
</script>
```

Html:

```
<textarea onkeyup="removerEmail(this)" onkeypress="removerEmail(this)">
</textarea>
```

[**Veja esse exemplo.**](http://regexr.com/3d3mn)

E no PHP usando um filtro para a linha que contiver o e-mail:

```
function filterEmail($text)
{
   return preg_replace('/(.*)[a-z0-9\.\_\-]+@[a-z0-9\.\_\-]+\.[a-z]+(.*)/i','', $text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei ao certo onde irá utilizar, mas quando eu preciso inibir o usuário de escrever, postar, enviar ou sei lá o que com o e-mail dele, eu uso um preg_replace com especificações como a baixo. e então o e-mail digitado é substituido por [O E-MAIL NAO PODE SER EXIBIDO]

```
$text = preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)/','[O E-MAIL NAO PODE SER EXIBIDO]', $text);
```

Comment: No caso ele não deleta a linha, pois as vezes além de apenas o e-mail, ele pode ter colocado alguma outra informação importante na linha!